# Switching low current AC

Tags: relay, switch

What is the simplest way to switch ON/OFF a 60v and 5 mA of current ? 
I don't want the common relays for arduinos as they make click noise.

Comment: Solid State Relay (SSR)?

Comment: e.g., Fotek SSR-10 DA for next to nothing on eBay...

Comment: Is there something smaller than SSR ? maybe Triac or similar

Comment: That's basically what is inside the SSR. A triac and a bit of control circuitry. BigClive does a teardown of one: https://youtu.be/DxEhxjvifyY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Following devices could be helpful in you case.

1. Power BJT as a switch (check datasheets if it comes on your required range).
2. Solid state relay is obviously, but cast is little high in this case.